# Angular - Form Array push specific index

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
addStop() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.editForm.controls['stops'];
    control.push(this.initStop());
}
```

I have this code to add a "stop" at the bottom of the form array. But I want to add the new "stop" not to the last position, but one position before the last stop.

This doesn't work for example (not at all, I know that the numbers are wrong. Splice function doesn't exist at )

```
control.splice(2, 0, this.initStop());
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [**FormArray#insert**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#insert):

```
control.insert(<index>, this.initStop());
```

Comment: And if index is not given for some reason, Infinity is also a valid value. It will add it to the end just like `push`