# Kendo : Insert a FormGroup at a top into a FormArray

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

**Problem Statement :**

In below stackblitz demo, I am able to insert the `FormGroup` dynamically at the starting of the grid on clicking the `Add` button and triggering the `(blur)` event from one control to update the value of another control sharing same `rowIndex`. Now the issue is if i inserted multiple `formGroups` and trigger on `(blur)` event on any of the newly added `FormGroups` it updates the value of other controls as well having different `rowIndex`.

**Steps to reproduce the issue :**

- Open the below demo link.
- Add multiple rows (2 rows) by clicking on the Add button.
- Enter the value in name field of the 2nd newly added row and focus out.
- It updates the age field in both the newly added row instead of only in second one.

**Stackblitz Demo :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oitz5j-4uezqr

**Requirement :**

Tab out on any name field of particular row, Age field on same row should display a random number without impacting other rows.

**What i tried so far ?**

- Tried to use Array [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method but getting error

  > Property 'unshift' does not exist on type 'FormArray'
- Tried to use [FormArray.insert()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) method.It will work if we want to add a `FormGroup` at specific index. But it fails to insert multiple `FormGroups` on the top of `FormArray` dynamically.

**Update :** Above issue is working fine without Kendo Grid. Please check the below demo.

**Demo :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oitz5j-2a31gs

**Related issues in github/stackoverflow :**

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16322

[Angular - Form Array push specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489034/angular-form-array-push-specific-index)

**Note :** If we are going to add the controls at the end of the Grid, it is working like a champ. Please check the below demo which works fine with adding the controls at the last.

**Demo :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oitz5j-aszrjq

Comment: For 1st demo, when I tried to replicate the steps, I can see error in the console. Is something got change in stackblitz?

Comment: @PankajParkar Sorry for that error. I corrected that. Can you please check now

Comment: Here's a fun part: Try calling the functions `addNewRow()` twice to add row and `onFocusOut(1)` to mock the expected behavior and everything works fine !

Comment: Trying to close in on the problem: You are creating new formgroup everytime the data changes, everytime you press the add button, you are inserting new group in the `addNewRow()` function and the `subscription` also.

Comment: @SachinGupta I am updating both data source as well as controls. You can check the demo without Kendo and its working fine.

Comment: @RohitJindal if you can check the form. After you add the rows, the form has double the controls each time.

Comment: @SachinGupta I did not get you. Can you provide the fix in stackblitz ?

Answer (score 6):

For those who wants to insert elements dynamically in FormArray initially then use Insert with index 0.

```
this.formName.controls.FieldNameArray.insert(0,[...])
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#insert.

Answer (score 2):

**Why isn't my code working?**

This isn't a Kendo issue at all. Your entire form is already being created every time the `view` observable is triggered. So when you add a row, you are basically adding to both the `items` in `createForm` as well as triggering the `view` observable (by calling `updateGridData`), which in turn adds to the `items` in `createForm`. Telerik seems to be doing the latter as seen in this [example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/#toc-rendering-editors-in-the-cell-templates) so we don't need to `insert` into `items` at all in `addNewRow`. Instead, just update `gridData` and then call `updateGridData`.

**Solution**

There are just two issues in your code. The first one being in your `view` subscribe block. The code you are using will basically just push on top of the previous `items` and not replace them. So we need to reinitialize the `items` `FormArray` here.

```js
this.view.subscribe(r => {
    this.createForm.setControl('items', new FormArray([]));

    r.data.forEach((i) => {
        const newRow = new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl(i.name),
            age: new FormControl(i.age)
        });
        (this.createForm.get("items") as FormArray).push(newRow);
    });
});
```

You could rewrite this using `map` like below.

```js
this.view.subscribe(r => {
    this.createForm.setControl('items', new FormArray(r.data.map(item =>
        new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl(item.name),
            age: new FormControl(item.age),
        })
    )));
});
```

Now all you need to do is assign `gridData` when a new row is added. We need to get the data entered by the user from `createForm` since `gridData` is not bound anywhere and will not contain the data which is entered by the user. There will be no need to do anything to the form here since the `view` subscribe block is already taking care of declaring `createForm`.

```js
addNewRow() {
    const blankRow = {
        name: "",
        age: ""
    };

    this.gridData = [blankRow, ...this.createForm.get('items').value];
    const data: GridDataResult = { data: this.gridData, total: this.gridData.length };
    this.editService.updateGridData(data);
}
```

The grid should now work.

**[Forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-grid-array)**

**Note**: The reason why the example where you are pushing a new row to the end of the grid works is that you are only declaring `createForm` once at the start in `ngOnInit`. Then you manually update the `gridData` and `insert` into `items`. There's no `updateGridData` here which triggers `view` to recreate `createForm`. If there was, even this wouldn't be working as expected.

Comment: There is one issue with the solution which you suggest as per our requirement. Reinitiate the FormArray agian everytime we add a new form group - Suppose we already have a n numbers of FormGroup with some custom validations on the controls. Hence, if we initialize the whole FormArray again just to add one new FormGroup will reset all the existing validations and may cause the performance issue to recreate the whole FormArray again with n number of FormGroups. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

#### How I started debugging:

I am not saying it is not weird but when you call that method `FormArray.insert` it inserts a copy of the existing formArray and concats with the current state. I added `console.log(formArray.controls)` and checked it was growing exponentially that means a snapshot was getting added every insert.

This led me to find out that you are subscribed to the `view` Observable and whenever it changes you are pushing all items in grid with the existing list.

---

#### How to fix it:

**Step 1**: In your addRow method remove the creation of formGroup and inserting to array as it is already handled in your view.subscribe method

```js
addNewRow() {
  ...
  /*
  <--- remove the creation of formgroup and adding to formarray taken care in next step --->
  if (this.createForm) {
     (this.createForm.get("items") as FormArray).insert(2, newRow);
  }
  */
}
```

**Step 2**: in your view.subscribe method change from push to insert. So the initial items will be inserted as well not pushed

```
this.view.subscribe(r => {
  r.data.forEach((data, i) => { //<-- Added index of the array
      const newRow = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(data.name),
        age: new FormControl(data.age),
      });
      if (this.createForm) {
        (this.createForm.get("items") as FormArray).insert(i, newRow);//<--changed to insert
      }
  });
});
```

**Step 3** now you want to unshift

```
addNewRow() {
  const blankRow = {
    name: "",
    age: "",
  };
  this.gridData.unshift(blankRow); //<-- you do it here.
  const data: GridDataResult = { data: this.gridData, total: this.gridData.length, }
  this.editService.updateGridData(data);
}
```

---

Updated Stackblitz for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oitz5j-ulhs4k

Comment: You can't use `unshift` here. Notice in your StackBlitz if you add a row, enter data in it and then add another row, the data you just entered will disappear.

Comment: There is one issue with the solution which you suggest as per our requirement. Reinitiate the FormArray agian everytime we add a new form group - Suppose we already have a n numbers of FormGroup with some custom validations on the controls. Hence, if we initialize the whole FormArray again just to add one new FormGroup will reset all the existing validations and may cause the performance issue to recreate the whole FormArray again with n number of FormGroups. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is Kendo-grid. you are stepping on the index 0 over and over of its data source 
and who knows what he will do internally to display the data. but what is true is that its not using the form array value. if you get out your from array of kendo grid will work fine or if you add in the end of your onFocusOut method a console log  `console.log(this.createForm.get("items").value);` you will see that the value of the formArray is fine.

If you need use yes or yes kendo grid. read the following doc:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-reactive-forms/

the examples that i see show that you cant handle externally the form. you need use the methods that kendo grid provide. because kendo grid dont display the fromArray value really

Comment: Yes, the problem is Kendo Grid, but if we are pushing the FormGroup at the end of FormArray its working fine. Only issue is in adding at the top.

Comment: Yes. Because when u add a element in a inexistent index and kendo grid dont have any item mapped with that index. When u step the index 0 break the internal mapping of kendo grid. See the examples. Kendo use a internal object to add new items to data source.