# how to use insert function in FormArray?

Tags: angular, formarray

I am tying to insert data by index it's not working 
i have sequence this sequence use as index but not patch properly

angualr.ts

```js
for (let key in this.existingCompanyObj) {
              companyControl.insert(Number(this.existingCompanyObj[key].sequence), this.fb.group({ company: this.companyNamesObj[key], role: this.existingCompanyObj[key].role, sequence: this.existingCompanyObj[key].sequence }));


[0:{company:company[0],role:role[0]},1:{company:company[1],role:role[1]};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Form Array push specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489034/angular-form-array-push-specific-index)

Comment: you have any example like that

Comment: Please format your code example properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert function not working properly use two for loop for that

```
for (let key in this.existingCompanyObj)
{    
 companyControl.push(new FormControl());
}
for (let key in this.existingCompanyObj
{
 companyControl.setControl(this.existingCompanyObj[key].sequence, this.fb.group({ company: 
 this.companyNamesObj[key], role: this.existingCompanyObj[key].role, sequence: 
 this.existingCompanyObj[key].sequence }));
}
```

first you need to **push(new FormControl)** blank formControl and then a sing value using **setControl(index object)**